# Save files into mysql database with the variables' values from address

Tags: php, mysql, html

I am new to the web design, I am currently trying to save pictures or other files together with some other values from web address into mysql database.

Let's say the web address is '**http://localhost/framework/file-upload.php?FinancialYear=2018&AssessmentRef=Soft_Launch&Site=NDC&QuestNo=1.2.2**'

The code works fine to save the files however the other values (**FinancialYear, AssessmentRef, Site and QuestionNo**) GET from the web address are not saved in the database, and really need your help.

[Mysql database settings and records however no values from web address saved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uLmw.png)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"> <!--fit in device width -->
        <link href="css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">             
    </head>



<?php

global $financial_year, $assessment_ref, $site, $quest_no;


if (isset($_GET['FinancialYear'])) {
    $financial_year = $_GET['FinancialYear'];
}

if (isset($_GET['AssessmentRef'])) {
    $assessment_ref = $_GET['AssessmentRef'];
}

if (isset($_GET['Site'])) {
    $site = $_GET['Site'];
}

if (isset($_GET['QuestNo'])) {
    $quest_no = $_GET['QuestNo'];
}

$quest_ref=$financial_year . $assessment_ref . $quest_no;

?>
<body>
<form action="file-upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">
    <p><I>Max 16MB per File</I></p>
</form>



<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    require_once './php-includes/connect.inc.php';


    $fileName=mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_FILES["file"]["name"]);   
    $fileData=mysqli_real_escape_string($db,file_get_contents($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]));
    $fileType=mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_FILES["file"]["type"]);

    mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO `files` VALUES('$financial_year', '$assessment_ref','$quest_no','$quest_ref','$site','$fileName','$fileType','$fileData',NOW(),'')");



}


?> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Append the GET values to the form as hidden inputs, or store them in the `SESSION` and call them as needed. If outputting the `GET` be sure to escape, `htmlspecialchars`.

Comment: I have tried put the GET values as hidden input, still not working. Or maybe I did it wrongly? Could you please do a sample code? Thanks

Comment: **Warning:** You should really use parameterized [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of manually escape and inject your variables into the query like that. Specially since you're not escaping all of the values.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @MagnusEriksson